# Slice URL to get the file name in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a file url and I need to slice it for showing the file to the users. I have successfully sliced it using `substring` but what if the string to slice isn't fixed. Like this `/media/users/3/sample.docx`. I wanted to show `sample.docx` only so I used `substring` but what if the numbers before that, increases like the number 3? How can do it the better way?

```
sliceString(value) {
   return value.substring(15)
}

{{sliceString(data.file)}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to use** `value.lastIndexOf()`

```
 sliceString(value) {
     return value.substring(value.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
 }

 {{sliceString(data.file)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take the last index of `/`, add `1` to it and use in the `substring` method :

```
sliceString(value) {
    let lastSlashIndex=value.lastIndexOf('/')
    return value.substring(lastSlashIndex+1)
}
```

Example:

```js
let url = 'sample.com/media/users/3/sample.docx'

let lastIndex= url.lastIndexOf('/');

console.log(url.substring(lastIndex+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
const url = 'sample.com/media/users/3/sample.docx';
url = url.split('/');
len = url.length;
const sample = url[len-1];
console.log(sample) // 'sample.docx'
```

Comment: This solution isn't generic. what if `url = 'sample.com/media/users/4/3/sample.docx'`?

Comment: It's generic for a certain purpose but not dynamic, good point. WIth the solution you provided is it possible to get something else than the last index? For example if the user would want to get the the content after the first slash.

Comment: if the user would want to get the the content after the first slash: `value.substring(url.indexOf("/"))`

Comment: Instead of using the index, use `return url.pop();`

Answer (score 0):

This should shrink the URL to just the filename even if there are query string parameters :

```
const fileString = 'file:///folder1/folder2/folder3/filename.extension?possibleQueries';
sliceURL = ((url) => {
    lastChar = url.length;
    if (url.lastIndexOf('?') > -1) {
        lastChar = url.lastIndexOf('?');
    };
    return (url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, lastChar));
})
(fileString); // Expected output: "filename.extension"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do it like that

```js
const url = 'sample.com/media/users/3/sample.docx'

console.log(url.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0])
```